# What is a list of research journals publishing quantum computing articles?

Tags: resource-request, research

Can anyone give me a list of different research journals that has quantum computing articles that I can use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is what I think is a comprehensive list of journals that publish papers about quantum information with a noteworthy frequency (anyone is free to edit/add more).

**Publishing only about quantum information**:

- Quantum Information & Computation
- Springer Quantum Information Processing
- Quantum Computing Frontiers
- npj Quantm Information

**Publishing papers, which includes papers on quantum information**:

- Physical Review A
- Physical Review B
- Physical Review X
- Physical Review E
- Physical Review Letters
- Physical Review X Quantum
- Physical Review Research
- Reviews of Modern Physics
- New Journal of Physics
- Journal of Chemical Physics
- Quantum Physics Letters
- Quantum - the open journal for quantum science
- Journal of Mathematical Physics
- Physics Letters A
- IEEE Transactions on Applied Superconductivity
- IEEE Transactions on Information Theory
- IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control
- Processing Entropy Journal
- AIP Advances
- Applied Physics Letters
- Annals of Physics
- Annalen der Physik
- Canadian Journal of Physics
- Journal of Applied Physics
- Journal of the Physical Society of Japan
- Nature Physics
- Nature Chemistry
- Nature Materials
- Nature
- Science
- Science Advances
- Scientific Repors
- Nature Communications
- European Physical Journal D
- European Physical Journal B
- Molecular Physics
- Laser Physics
- Journal of Physics B
- Review of Scientific Instruments
- Applied Optics
- Optics Express
- Optics Letters
- Nature Photonics
- Computer Physics Communications
- Journal of Physics: Condensed Matter
- Physica Status Solidi
- Chemical Physics Letters
- Physical Chemistry Chemical Physics
- Journal of Physical Chemistry A
- Journal of Physical Chemistry Letters
- Communications in Mathematical Physics
- Electronic Journal of Theoretical Physics
- SIAM Journal of Computing
- SIAM Journal on Scientific and Statistical Computing ([Shor's algorithm](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0097539795293172))
- Quantum Science and Technology (IOP)
- Advanced Quantum Technologies (Wiley)
- Quantum Machine Intelligence (Springer)

Comment: What is the url for Quantum Computing Frontiers?

Comment: @JoãoBravo you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 9):

There are loads of different quantum computing journals, so you might want to be more specific about what you're looking for. However, the vast majority of papers (certainly theory, perhaps a bit less so the experiments) appear as preprints on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/), specifically the [quant-ph section](https://arxiv.org/archive/quant-ph). The majority of papers, all in one place, collectively searchable, and free to read. What more could you ask for? If it's been published, usually it'll link to the published version as well (that depends on the author updating the record).

As with any paper you read, you'll have to make up your own mind about the validity of any paper you find on the arXiv, but these haven't necessarily been through peer review, or have been through peer review of varying degrees of rigour, depending on the ultimate publication journal.

Answer (score 4):

We should add that applied quantum computing is also covered as on-topic by the new cross-disciplinary journals:

(IOP) Quantum Science and Technology

(Wiley) Advanced Quantum Technologies

(Springer) Quantum Machine Intelligence

Comment: I have no idea!
I guess someone really doesn't like IOP, Wiley or Springer as editors.
I am in favor of supporting the emerging platforms of opensource science (see: 
https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/jun/27/profitable-business-scientific-publishing-bad-for-science) but I am also not against attempts to create valid interdisciplinary for-profit journals, as long as they allow posting on the arXiv.
What I am against is journals such as "NPJ Scientific Reports" which try to capitalize on the Nature brand while offering close-to-zero quality quality review of the submitted papers.

Answer (score 3):

I mostly work on quantum error correction and quantum information theory, so I can give you references about journals that cover such topics. Anyway, I am pretty sure that articles about quantum computing in general do also get published in such journals. I give you a list of them:

- IEEE transactions on Information Theory
- Physical Review Letters
- Physical Review A
- Physical Review X
- Springer Quantum Information Processing
- Entropy Journal

Take into account that those journals aer not in general only dedicated to quantum computing, so you must look for the articles related to the topic you are looking for in them. Also, arXiv is a really good place to look for papers in any topic, as most of the author publish their preprints/papers in such site.