# Is there any Q1 journal for quantum computing that is free for authors?

Tags: resource-request

I know there are some good journals that accept quantum computing articles, but unfortunately they charge authors a fee.

Are there any Q1 journals in this field which don't charge authors?

Comment: Hi reza! I took the liberty to edit this question since its original form conflated access model (open- vs closed-access) and payment model (who to charge: readers, authors, advertisers, some mix etc). I assumed your intention was to find a Q1 journal without publication fees. If your intention was instead to find closed-access journals, feel free to edit to that effect. Conflating access and payment models makes the question unclear and could even be viewed as baiting (either of which qualifies for vote-to-close).

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8783/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4204/55